# An alternative to 'selectionChange' event?

Tags: ckeditor, selection, selectionchanged

I want to execute a function after the user hilites some text.

I was hoping to listen for the 'selectionChange' event for that purpose, but the documentation states that it doesn't fire for every case, plus I've noticed that it actually also fires just by clicking into the editable area.  Is there another event the my plugin can listen for?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.$.addEventListener('selectionchange', function (e) { //selection change logic goes here });
```